# How to calculate the CRC of data to verify it with the CRC of a zip entry?

Tags: java, zip, checksum, crc

Before we get started: I am an absolute beginner with JAVA. I have always been a C++ coder. So please do tell me when I am doing stupid stuff here!

I am querying a huge database and exporting that data directly into a zip-file. We are talking about 35GB of data here, so the results are streamed through a StringBuilder and when that StringBuilder has a specific size, its data is sent to the ZipOutputStream object for compression. I reset the StringBuilder and repeat until all data has been processed and zipped.
This works fine. The zip files are always good, but the client wants me to put in extra checks.

So I want to be able to calculate the checksum value myself from that in memory data so that at the end, I can reopen the zip-file to check if it is not corrupt and the checksum is what I expect it to be.

So everytime I send data to the ZipOuputStream, I also update my internal checksum. I use the CRC32 class for this, which is also in the same zip library, so I would expect that zip entries use that same calculation.

But alas... the calculated checksum and the zip entry's checksum are not the same while the zip file definitely is ok.

Can anyone help me get this right?

Here is some code.
This is how I create a zip file, a CRC class and a StringBuilder.

```
File zipFile = new File(outputZipFileName);
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(tableName + ".csv");
zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
CRC32 zipEntryCrc = new CRC32();
StringBuilder sbZipData = new StringBuilder();
sbZipData.ensureCapacity(memoryBufferSize);
```

This is what I do every time when the StringBuilder reaches a limit or at the end of data:

```
byte[] sZipData = sbZipData.toString().getBytes();
zipEntryCrc.update(sZipData);
zipOut.write(sZipData, 0, sZipData.length);
zipOut.flush();
sbZipData.setLength(0);
```

Here's how I reopen my generated zip file and test the checksum:

```
ZipFile testZipFile = new ZipFile(outputZipFileName);
ZipEntry testZipEntry = testZipFile.getEntry(tableName + ".csv");
System.out.format("Calculated CRC: %8X, Zip entry CRC: %8X\n", zipEntryCrc.getValue(), testZipEntry.getCrc());
testZipFile.close();
```

As you can guess, the output is not the same:

```
Calculated CRC: 2E9F53AC, Zip entry CRC: 5270784D
```

Btw. I know I have to put some try-catches around to prevent the code from stopping when the zip entry is not found. This is just my first test.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your example and it does work, the checksum is identical, but, I needed to add at least the `zipOut.close()` call:

```
    zipOut.write(sZipData, 0, sZipData.length);
    //zipOut.closeEntry();     // <===== optional
    zipOut.flush();
    zipOut.close();            // <=====
    sbZipData.setLength(0);
```

Here the complete test class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class CRC32Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create test daata
        String input = "Hell is empty and all the devils are here. William Shakespeare";
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            input = input + "|" + input;
        }
        System.out.println("input length: " + input.length());

        // get bytes from string
        byte bytes[] = input.getBytes();

        // compute checksum
        Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
        checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        // get current checksum value
        long checksumValue = checksum.getValue();

        System.out.format("CRC32 checksum for input string: %8X\n", checksumValue);
        System.out.println("------------------");

        String outputZipFileName = "t.zip";
        int memoryBufferSize = 1024;
        String tableName = "string";
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        File zipFile = new File(outputZipFileName);
        if (zipFile.exists()) zipFile.delete();

        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile), charset);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(tableName + ".csv");
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        CRC32 zipEntryCrc = new CRC32();
        StringBuilder sbZipData = new StringBuilder();
        sbZipData.ensureCapacity(memoryBufferSize);

        sbZipData.append(input);   // <=====

        byte[] sZipData = sbZipData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        zipEntryCrc.update(sZipData);
        zipOut.write(sZipData, 0, sZipData.length);
        //zipOut.closeEntry();     // <===== optional
        zipOut.flush();
        zipOut.close();            // <=====
        sbZipData.setLength(0);

        ZipFile testZipFile = new ZipFile(outputZipFileName, charset);
        ZipEntry testZipEntry = testZipFile.getEntry(tableName + ".csv");
        System.out.format("Calculated CRC: %8X, Zip entry CRC: %8X\n", zipEntryCrc.getValue(), testZipEntry.getCrc());
        testZipFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works indeed, but handles only one buffer. I have added another buffer to simulate more what I am doing, but it still works fine. I also closed the zipOut, so that's not it. I'll look further. Many thanks for giving me a working example. Edit: FOUND IT! Something you couldn't have seen because I didn't add the code. I forgot that I had added a CSV header before doing the whole loop thing and I forgot to calculate the CRC for that part as well.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!